# Using nls in R to re-create research

Tags: r, nls

I am learning how to use the nls function in R and am having some issues.  I am simply attempting to recreate the curve found in a research paper for now.  The model fits a curve to the the stock market movements prior to the 1987 crash.

I have defined a function, func, as follows:

```
func <- function(a,b,tc,t){
 a+b*log(tc-t)
}
```

I have called nls like this:

```
nls1 <- nls(Y ~ func(a,b,tc,t), data2, start=list(a=0, b=1, tc=1466, t=1))
```

data2 is a data frame that consists of two columns, one is the date, the other is a value.  There are 1466 rows.

```
head(data2)
 Date      Y
1  1/4/82 882.52
2  1/5/82 865.30
3  1/6/82 861.02
4  1/7/82 861.78
5  1/8/82 866.53
6 1/11/82 850.46
```

I get the following messages when I run nls,

```
Error in qr(.swts * attr(rhs, "gradient")) : 
  dims [product 4] do not match the length of object [1466]

In addition: Warning message:

In .swts * attr(rhs, "gradient") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

From what I can gather, this is a problem with the way the data frame is set up but I cannot find a solution.

Any idea how I can move this father along?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 8):

The basic problem is that you have not specified an independent variable. By specifying `start(...)` for `a, b, tc, and t`, you are telling `nls(...)` that these are all parameters of the model.

It looks like you are using a simplified version of the LPPL model, in which `a, b, and tc` are parameters, and `t` is the independent variable. It looks like `data2$Date` contains the time variable. You need to make sure the `data2$Date` is of class POSIXct. So you could write:

```
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%y")
nls1 <- nls(Y~a+b*log(tc-Date), data=data2, start=list(a=0, b=1, tc=1466))
```

**EDIT:** In response to OP's comments

This is a great question, because it illustrates several issues in using `nls(...)`. The problem you are having (now that the model is specified correctly) is that `nls(...)` is not converging - a distressingly common occurrence. Basically, unless your starting parameter estimates are relatively close to the final, fitted values (or unless the model is extremely "well behaved"), nls will fail. [Note also that the paper you cite mentions that b is restricted to b < 0, whereas you are starting with b=1.] So what to do?

The `minpack.lm(...)` function in package `minpack` uses the exceptionally robust Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm for non-linear least squares estimation. In fact, the paper you cite mentions L-M specifically. The problem with `minpack.lm(...)` is that it is much more difficult to use (you have to define a function which returns the residuals at a given step, rather than just defining the function to fit). Plus, `minpack.lm(...)` does not calculate statistics of the fit.

So the solution is to use them both! Use `minpack.lm(...)` to estimate the parameters, then use those as "starting values" in `nls(...)`. The code below does that. Having a model fitted using `nls(...)` will make it much easier to generate statistics of the fit, predicted values, residuals, and also to apply the model to new datasets.

```
# this section just grabs the DJIA for 1982 - 1987; you already have this
library(tseries)
library(zoo)
ts <- get.hist.quote(instrument="DJIA", 
                     start="1982-01-01", end="1987-08-01", 
                     quote="Close", provider="yahoo", origin="1970-01-01",
                     compression="d", retclass="zoo")
df <- data.frame(ts)
df <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(rownames(df)),Y=df$Close)
df <- df[!is.na(df$Y),]
# end of setup...
library(minpack.lm) # for nls.lm(...)
library(ggplot2)    # for ggplot
df$days <- as.numeric(df$Date - df[1,]$Date)
# model based on a list of parameters
f <- function(pars, xx) {pars$a + pars$b*log(pars$tc - xx)} 
# residual function
resids <- function(p, observed, xx) {df$Y - f(p,xx)}
# fit using Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm
nls.out <- nls.lm(par=list(a=1,b=-1,tc=5000), fn = resids, 
                  observed = df$Y, xx = df$days)
# use output of L-M algorithm as starting estimates in nls(...)
par <- nls.out$par
nls.final <- nls(Y~a+b*log(tc-days),data=df, 
                 start=c(a=par$a, b=par$b, tc=par$tc))
summary(nls.final)      # display statistics of the fit 
# append fitted values to df
df$pred <- predict(nls.final)
# plot the results
ggplot(df)+
  geom_line(aes(x=Date,y=Y),color="black")+
  geom_line(aes(x=Date,y=pred),color="blue",linetype=2)+
  labs(title="LPPL Model Applied to DJIA (1982 - 1987)",
       x="", y="DJIA (daily close)")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold"))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent suggestion, thank you.  It has moved me along.  When I run the nls1 line, I get the following error, Error in `-.POSIXt`(tc, Date) : can only subtract from "POSIXt" objects.  I imagine this has to do with the fact that tc is an integer, not a date.

Comment: Regarding the methodology and why this particular equation was chosen, here is the academic article I am working off of that explains the rationale, http://www.chronostraders.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/LP-clusters.pdf

Comment: @user2926358 - see my edits above re: why are you still getting errors.

Comment: It's funny how this works sometimes. I have spent a good portion of the day research LPPL modeling and see the issues that you raised.  I initially was going to try the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm you mentioned, but had issues installing minpack so decided to try to keep it simple.  With all of th reading I have done today, it is clear that using LPPL is a complex problem. Thank you for your comments, I will begin working with it shortly.

Comment: One quick note on the code above, when I first opened R a few months ago, the course I was taking mentioned !is.na.  I found this confusing as a newcomer, meaning I couldn't get it to work, and instead used na.omit.  It seems more straightforward to me.

Comment: Alright, I think I need to call it a day.  I did get to the end of this using S&P 500 data.  Dow Jones data is not available to be downloaded from Yahoo, some sort of licensing issue. I will look at this some more tomorrow and substitute in the Dow Jones data I downloaded.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that `nls` will work if you ensure that the argument to log cannot go negative and use the `"plinear"` algorithm which only requires starting values for the non-linear parameters (in this case `tc`).  `nls(Y ~ cbind(1, log(abs(tc - days))), df, start = c(tc = 5000), alg = "plinear")`

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when one performs a least squares regression, the assumption is that there is a so-called "dependent" or "response" variable (`Y`, in your case), which is a function of one or more "independent" or "predictor" variables (`Date`), and typically the detailed specification of the predictor function itself is usually defined by a fairly small number of static parameters (`a` and `b`, and possibly also `t` and/or `tc` as well, depending on what exactly it is that you are trying to achieve).  The job of the `nls()` function is to find the optimal values for those static parameters which would lead to the most accurate possible prediction.

The input to your predictor function `func` appears to be missing the required independent variable.  So, I think you probably need to do one of two things.  Either you modify `func` so that it accepts `Date` as an input, or else you change the `Date` column label in your data frame so that the name matches one of the `func` inputs (most likely I suspect that you would want to rename the `Date` column so that it corresponds to `tc`).  In either case, if you want to perform a calculation in which you subtract a date value in the data frame from a fixed offset date (e.g., `(tc - t)` as it appears to be written right now), you will need to check that R is actually recognizing your dates as Date objects and not as strings, so that it knows how to meaningfully subtract one from the other.  The `as.Date()` function may be helpful to you for this purpose.

As an additional alternative, rather than trying to rewrite `func` so that it accepts R Date objects as inputs, you may find it simpler just to reassign the `Date` column in the data frame to an elapsed integer number of days with reference to some offset; e.g., do something like:

```
data2$tc <- as.numeric(as.Date(data2$Date) - as.Date("1982-1-4"))
```

or similar.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.  I went with your 3rd option as that is the simplest.  I did away with func altogether and used this from jlhoward's suggestion above.  nls1 <- nls(value~a+b*log(tc-t), data=data2, start=list(a=882, b=1, tc=1000)).  I receveid the following error, Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model